# $ brew install gcc@7 suspiciously fast

Tags: gcc, g++, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I just recently reinstalled homebrew, and prior to tonight had only ran `$ brew tap homebrew/science`. I just ran `$ brew install gcc@7 --without-multilib` in order to properly `make` the bioinformatics program trinity-rnaseq, and it just installed at an unusually fast rate compared to what I'm used to with `$ brew install gcc`. I'm used to it taking 40-50 minutes, but it just seemingly installed with all dependencies in about 5 minutes. I guess that I'm just suspicious as to why it only took 10% of the normal time to install, and was wondering if anybody knows of any way to test that this install worked properly. I went ahead and attached my terminal output below, just in case it sheds any light on this.

`My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ brew install gcc@7 --without-multilib
==> Installing dependencies for gcc: gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl
==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp-6.1.2_1.high_sierra.bot`
`########################################################################` `100.0%
==> Pouring gmp-6.1.2_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_1: 18 files, 3.1MB
==> Installing gcc dependency: mpfr
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mpfr-3.1.6.high_sierra.bott`
`######################################################################## 100.0%`
`==> Pouring mpfr-3.1.6.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.6: 26 files, 3.6MB
==> Installing gcc dependency: libmpc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libmpc-1.0.3_1.high_sierra.`
`######################################################################## 100.0%`
`==> Pouring libmpc-1.0.3_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/libmpc/1.0.3_1: 12 files, 345.1KB
==> Installing gcc dependency: isl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/isl-0.18.high_sierra.bottle`
`######################################################################## 100.0%`
`==> Pouring isl-0.18.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/isl/0.18: 80 files, 3.8MB
Warning: gcc: this formula has no --without-multilib option so it will be ignored!
==> Installing gcc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-7.2.0.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz`
`######################################################################## 100.0%`
`==> Pouring gcc-7.2.0.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0: 1,487 files, 284.3MB`

When I check which packages I have installed, and where gcc-7 is installed, all seems normal. I'm honestly not *too* terribly familiar with homebrew and gcc, so my apologies for any blatant ignorance on my part here.

`My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ brew list
gcc gmp isl libmpc  mpfr`

`My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ which gcc-7
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7`

Comment: Perhaps you had already grabbed/compiled many dependencies, so the final process took much less time?

Comment: That's what I was beginning to think. I remember reading somewhere that if you pull a precompiled version or had some dependencies ahead of time, it is far quicker. Since I'm still relatively new to Unix, I thought that I'd ask a more informed community.

Thank you!

Comment: See whether it works.  If it works — and the stuff you show being installed looks plausible — then don't fret.  If it doesn't work, then worry.

Comment: Compilation went just fine. I guess that Qwertycracker's answer ended up being the case!